# Russell's paradox question

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, paradoxes

Tao's analysis book uses following example for Russell's paradox:
$$P(x) \Longrightarrow `` x\text{ is a set, and }x \notin  x"\\
\Omega := \{x : P(x)\text{ is true} \} = \{x : x\text{ is a set and }x \notin x\}$$
then conclude that $­\Omega \in \Omega$ and $­\Omega \notin \Omega$ happened same time. so it is a paradox. 
My question is if $x$ is a set, you can't write $x \notin  x$ right? only element belong to a set, isn't the statement wrong at the first place? or this could not be called as a statement.

Comment: "only elements belong to a set"  - these 'elements' could themselves be sets, e.g. $$\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$$

Comment: The paradox arises when you assume that $\Omega$ is a set: in such a case $\Omega \in \Omega$ if and only if $\Omega \notin \Omega$. So, to avoid this contradiction, necesarily $\Omega$ is a collection of sets which is not a set.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a set, then $\Omega \notin \Omega$ is always a true statement right? we define $\emptyset = \{\}$, $0 = \{\{\}\}$, then $\{\{\}\} \notin \{\{\}\}$ is always correct?

Comment: a set is an element, but a set can never belong to himself right?

Comment: A set cannot belong to itself in ZF set theory.  Russel's paradox was a reason for formulating some axioms for set theory, such as the ZF axioms.  But Frege's system had no such restriction, which allowed Russel to some up with this paradox.  It showed Frege's system of set theory was **no good**.  If $\Omega$ is "the set of all sets" (something Frege's theory allowed) then certainly $\Omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: No, you can write $x\in x$ and $x\notin x$; they're a well-formed formula. But $x\in x$ is false in ZF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking "pre-theoretically" - that is, in naive set theory, before we fix a formal system of axioms - there is no reason that a set can't be an element of itself! And in fact, even in formalized set theory it can be okay: in the usual set theory, $ZFC$ (or its variants), this is ruled out by the **axiom of foundation**, but there are set theories such as $NF$ ("New Foundations") or the "anti-Foundation" set theories (Boffa, Aczel, . . .) which *do* allow sets to be elements of themselves.

In fact, in $NF$, the "set of all sets" *does* exist, and is an element of itself! $NF$ escapes Russell's paradox by not allowing full comprehension, or even full separation: just because $A$ is a set, doesn't mean (in $NF$) that the collection of all $x\in A$ satisfying some formula is a set.

The point is that, surprising as it may be, there is no reason to outlaw a set being an element of itself from the get-go. If we think of sets as properties, then we should in fact *expect* this: after all, the property "is a property" is a property! :P

Answer (score 3):

Sets are mathematical objects which are collections of mathematical objects. In particular, sets can be elements of other sets.

There is no reason for discrimination against sets. However, what Russell's paradox shows is that not every "expressible collection" of mathematical objects is a set. This is a naive belief which turns out to be false.

Comment: Can you further explain a little bit?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not set self-membership. If we assume $$Set(r) \land \forall x:[x\in r \iff Set(x) \land x\notin x]$$ and apply nothing more than the rules of logic (no set theory), then we can obtain the contradiction $$r\in r \land r\notin r$$

where $Set(r)$ means $r$ is a set.

Therefore, we conclude that no such set $r$ can exist. (A similar argument holds without the $Set$ predicate.)

In an early attempt to axiomatize set theory which used the same rules of logic, there was a very powerful axiom  (too powerful as it turned out) that for every unary predicate $P$, there existed a set $S$ such that $\forall x:[x\in S \iff P(x)]$. Of course, $P(x)\equiv Set(x) \land x\notin x$ led to the above contradiction. Using this early set theory, you could both prove and disprove the existence of the set $r$. Clearly, this powerful axiom had to be replaced by other less powerful axiom(s). Various patches were subsequently proposed. The most popular are the ZFC axioms of set theory which effectively banned set self-membership anyway. It should be noted that other popular set theories do not ban set self-membership.

Comment: Have you read the question?